# Downloading Points of Interest from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, point-of-interest

Is there any legal way to search and download google maps POI information, based on user location and search radius (50 km) + search criteria (eg restaurant) ?

Output would ideally be KML or CSV.

Answer (score 6):

No. I am unaware of any legal way to bulk download Google's POI database. Many alternates exists including free options such as [OSM](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/15/getting-point-of-interest-data-from-openstreetmap) and purchase options such as [HERE](http://mapdataservices.com/mapping-data-points-of-interest). A simple web search will reveal many more.

Now, although you cannot download Google's POIs in a traditional manner the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) will give you access to over 100 million Google POIs or places. This API allows such functionality as search nearby, search within a radius, and search for a type such as restaurant and so it meets most of your requirements as stated in the question aside from a traditional batch download.