# Is it possible to export data from google maps?

Tags: data, google-maps, export

I plan to create a map using food-restaurant locations in Manhattan, NY. Since there is a large quantity of densely located restaurants it would be a pain to collect it by hand.

Is it possible to export the points that appear when you google maps "restaurants near me" into a spreadsheet with atleast the Address/GEOID and restaurant name?

Comment: It's unlikely that Google would give this data away for free, since they've either purchased it themselves, or invested heavily to create it.  You're probably going to have to purchase the data from a third party company.

Comment: maybe you could download this dataset of food safety grades http://www1.nyc.gov/site/doh/services/restaurant-grades.page

Comment: And remember to check the licence of the data you get (I don't think google would allow the use of their data for anything else that personal use, OSM let you do what you want but you have to attribute the data and to share)

Answer (score 11):

If I may suggest an alternative, you could use data from Open Street Map (OSM).

From the OSM webpage: "OpenStreetMap is open data: you are free to use it for any purpose as long as you credit OpenStreetMap and its contributors. If you alter or build upon the data in certain ways, you may distribute the result only under the same licence." (http://www.openstreetmap.org/about)

One easy way to download a dataset from OSM is through the Overpass Turbo Wizard at https://overpass-turbo.eu. Set a bounding box (to reduce the size of your results), then use the 'Wizard' button to open the Wizard and search for the word 'restaurant'

[image]

[image: Overpass Turbo Wizard dialogue]

Here's what the result looks like:

[image: data for a search of restaurants in the New York City area]

Comment: or use the API with QGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/329844/seeking-shapefile-from-specific-city/329853#329853

Answer (score 5):

As far as I am concerned the answer is **No**. Google does not provide data for free.

Similar question was posted in the past: [Google maps POI download](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31927/google-maps-poi-download)

Answer (score -2):

You can try this Google Maps data extractor: http://estrattoredati.com/local-business-extractor.html

Comment: Does anyone have information on the legality of that? Seems like they scrape Google Maps results, which I would be surprised to see not forbidden by googles Terms of Service.