# Seeking shapefile from specific city?

Tags: coordinates

Where can I find a shapefile from a specific city?

I am looking from a shapefile from Valencia (Spain). I only find files from the [entire country](https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/eea-reference-grids-2/gis-files/spain-shapefile). I want a specific shapefile with some polygons where I can filter a given point from the city and discover if it is in that polygon.

Can I download it from Google Maps?

Comment: If the *all cities* has the data you need, why not simply copy that data out of the original and move on? Without mention of software in use it's not possible to give further guidance.

Comment: You could also look at https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v1/

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then a place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use QGIS and create a OSM query to achieve that. You need the plugin "QuickOSM"

In QuickOSM You fill the fields as seen here:

[image]

and your result is the boundary of the city Valencia :)

it includes all available administrative levels. to get only the inner-city districts:

right click the temporary polygon layer, make it editable and delete all non-innercity districts (they are overlaying the innercity-districts).

To see which are actually districts interesting for you, check the attribute table and have a look at the column "admin_level". OSM Wiki explains what the numbers are standing for:

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3aboundary=administrative#10_admin_level_values_for_specific_countries

Optionally export the temporary layer to a permanent one.

Comment: Hey, that's great! I have never looked into this plugin before, and now I certainly will!

Comment: Hi, indeed, it is really nice. I just installed QGIS on my ubuntu and the plugins necessary. Then I downloaded the map of Spain (https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/spain.html) and executed the query that you told to me. However, I want some regions inside Valencia. For example the districts. I need this to check if a coordinate is inside some district.

Comment: Perhaps https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html has what you want.

Comment: @Felipe The districts are only covered under the larger polygon covering the whole area of the city (admin level 1 i assume) - you might be more interested in admin_level 8 and 9. I updated my answer accordingly :)

Comment: @sn1ks Awesome! It was a piece of cake! Do you know how to export it to polygons? My final goal is to create a Java Program using GeoTools which says if a given coordinate is inside these polygons (The valencia administrative areas number 9).

Comment: open attribute table -> select by expression ->  "admin_level" = 8 OR "admin_level" = 9 -> close attribute table -> right click on layer -> export -> save selected features as -> done :)

Answer (score 3):

If you happen to be using QGIS, this Plugin seems to do what you're asking for quite easily.

https://github.com/sigdeletras/Spanish_Inspire_Catastral_Downloader

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot download the data from Google Maps.

There is a wealth of data if you simply conduct a basic Google Search, but it is offered by a disparate array of national/regional/etc. entities for all locales.

If you are looking for data related to Spain, look through the data offered by Centro de Descargas: http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/index.jsp